# Can I use c# source code(A) instead of corresponding DLL(A) to compile another DLL(B) which was built with the references of DLL(A)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm dealing with such problem:

1. I've compiled a "Ref.dll" with the C# source code, it has no references.
2. I've compiled a "Tool.dll" with the C# source code, and it has a reference DLL "Ref.dll".
3. If I put these two DLLs into my Unity Project, it works.
4. When I have to put only the "Tool.dll" into my Project, it will occur an error:

   ```
   Assembly 'xxx/Tool.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
   Unable to resolve reference 'Ref'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
   ```
5. Can I just use the source code of "Ref.dll" instead of the "Ref.dll" itself to make my compilation of "Tool.dll" succeed?

Comment: The *compilation* of Tool.dll appears to already be successful. As for the *use* of Tool.dll, yes, you can incorporate the entire source code of Ref into Tool instead of having a reference to Ref.

Comment: Just remember to remove the reference to Ref.dll, or Tool.dll still wouldn't load.

Comment: Hi, GSerg! How can I make Tool.dll usable with a bunch of "Ref source code" in the same project? Here's the situation: In a project, there's only one compiled Tool.dll and the "Ref source code". I can hardly get the point of "incorporate Ref source code into Tool.dll"

Comment: Hi, Dialecticus! What's the way for me to remove the reference to Ref.dll from a compiled Tool.dll?

Comment: @VisualEugen when calling other people here you should use the @ sign, so it's `@Dialecticus` instead of `Dialecticus`. I will then get a notification that someone called me. To remove a reference go to Solution Explorer, Tool project, References item, and there just Delete a reference.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thanks for your reply! If I remove the reference in my Tool c# project, I cannot compile it. But how I can edit a compiled DLL?

Comment: Give us please the text of build output. Add it to your question. It's in the Output tab.